# Google sheet currency (changable)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-cell-format

I was usually working on Excel sheets, in which I had option to choose currency (file was used as a template). It was based on Conditional formatting and simple formulas so it worked like charm.
So it look like this. I have a drop down list with couple currencies. I chose one, and the formatting of tables is based on this choice.

Now I have to prepare similar document on Google Sheets but there is where I have problem. Conditional formatting in GSheets is not that sophisticated as in Excel. so my question is:

Is there a simple way to choose currency used in multiple tables? Any way to make formatting depend and on cell value?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). If you still have the Microsoft Excel file, you can convert it into a Google Sheet. Almost all formatting should follow, including conditional formatting for things like conditional cell borders that cannot be set through the user interface in Google Sheets. If you need more help, share a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data. Show your _hand-entered_ expected results there. Use **Insert > Note** to describe what you want.

Comment: Yes, i do have it - I was working on it for some time. 
As for importing to google sheet - it does containt normal conditional formatting (so changing colors based on value etc. ) but it does not contain currency values. 
The lin for dummy file is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QlEQEJrQhpG7CXKH9SzCqryVDn93qSkZ/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115886863290484567929&rtpof=true&sd=true

As for my progress, i only found that it might be done in GSheets with use of scritps, i don't see any information how to apply cell format to a cell (is this even possible?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a variable currency using a separate reporting sheet that copies the values from the `Tracker` sheet with formulas like these:

```
={ Tracker!B1:5 }

={ Tracker!B6:C26 }

=arrayformula( 
  text( 
    Tracker!D6:E26; 
    regexextract('Delivery Outline'!$C$5; "\((..?)\)") 
    & 
    " #,###,##0.00" 
  ) 
)
```

The `text()` function in the latter formula observes the currency selected in the `Delivery Outline` sheet.

See the new '[Tracker - report](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QlEQEJrQhpG7CXKH9SzCqryVDn93qSkZ/edit#gid=1574236219)' sheet in your sample spreadsheet. The formulas are in the cells that have been marked yellow.

Comment: Hey, 
Thank You for that update - maybe not a perfect solution, but  that is some workaround since I need to change the currency for different reporting.
Only problem is, i understand i would need to duplicate all sheets to create that connection between both tables correct? 
I might just use that formulas to create a Report template, choose currency, and afterwards just save it as 'template' - it might be some timesaving then - any way Thank you very much for help ;)

Comment: Ahh yes, 
Thank you :)